# Convert json to datatable vb

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization, datatable, deserialization

Good morning,
today i was trying to convert my json to datatable.

This is what i'm trying to do

```
    Dim webclient_server7 As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim json_result As String = webclient_server7.DownloadString("http://myhost/api/mycontroller/GetQuery")
    Dim json_jsonstring = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json_result)

    Try
        Dim table As DataTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(json_jsonstring)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("An exception occured: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

And i get an exception saying:
 An exception occured: Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got String. Path '', line 1, position 9919.

i validated my json on [json lint](http://jsonlint.com/) and it says my json is valid.
Is there anyone who can help me fixing this?
here's a copy of my raw json

> "{\r\n  \"Table\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"IdOwner\": \"Davide\",\r\n      \"tag_id\": 1,\r\n      \"tag_type\": \"3\",\r\n      \"tag_group\": \"Group_2\",\r\n      \"tag_name\": \"Alfa\",\r\n      \"tag_sequence\": 123458,\r\n      \"tag_description\": \"Description_2\",\r\n      \"tag_short_descritpion\": \"Desc_2\",\r\n      \"tag_um\": \"kg\",\r\n      \"tag_active\": true,\r\n      \"tag_collecting\": false,\r\n      \"tag_data_edit\": true,\r\n      \"tag_source_name\": \"Alfaservice\",\r\n      \"tag_source_index\": \"Undefined_index\",\r\n      \"tag_source_tagtype\": \"Source_tag_type\",\r\n      \"tag_source_lenght\": 50,\r\n      \"tag_collect_frequency\": 200,\r\n      \"tag_collect_unit\": \"ms\",\r\n      \"tag_low_limit\": 100.0,\r\n      \"tag_high_limit\": 370.0,\r\n      \"tag_control_limit_active\": true,\r\n      \"tag_calc\": \"useless_field\",\r\n      \"tag_level\": 0,\r\n      \"tag_origine_dati\": null\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"IdOwner\": \"Giuseppe\",\r\n      \"tag_id\": 3,\r\n      \"tag_type\": \"Type_1\",\r\n      \"tag_group\": \"Group_2\",\r\n      \"tag_name\": \"Bemad\",\r\n      \"tag_sequence\": 123456,\r\n      \"tag_description\": \"Description_5\",\r\n      \"tag_short_descritpion\": \"Desc_5\",\r\n      \"tag_um\": \"Kg\",\r\n      \"tag_active\": true,\r\n      \"tag_collecting\": false,\r\n      \"tag_data_edit\": true,\r\n      \"tag_source_name\": \"Alfaservice\",\r\n      \"tag_source_index\": \"Undefined_index\",\r\n      \"tag_source_tagtype\": \"Source_tag_type\",\r\n      \"tag_source_lenght\": 50,\r\n      \"tag_collect_frequency\": 200,\r\n      \"tag_collect_unit\": \"ms\",\r\n      \"tag_low_limit\": 250.0,\r\n      \"tag_high_limit\": 660.0,\r\n      \"tag_control_limit_active\": true,\r\n      \"tag_calc\": \"useless_field\",\r\n      \"tag_level\": 0,\r\n      \"tag_origine_dati\": null\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"IdOwner\": \"Madalin\",\r\n      \"tag_id\": 2,\r\n      \"tag_type\": \"Type_2\",\r\n      \"tag_group\": \"Group_1\",\r\n      \"tag_name\": \"Bemad\",\r\n      \"tag_sequence\": 123456,\r\n      \"tag_description\": \"Description_1\",\r\n      \"tag_short_descritpion\": \"Desc_1\",\r\n      \"tag_um\": \"Kg\",\r\n      \"tag_active\": true,\r\n      \"tag_collecting\": false,\r\n      \"tag_data_edit\": true,\r\n      \"tag_source_name\": \"Alfaservice\",\r\n      \"tag_source_index\": \"Undefined_index\",\r\n      \"tag_source_tagtype\": \"Source_tag_type\",\r\n      \"tag_source_lenght\": 50,\r\n      \"tag_collect_frequency\": 200,\r\n      \"tag_collect_unit\": \"ms\",\r\n      \"tag_low_limit\": 150.0,\r\n      \"tag_high_limit\": 350.0,\r\n      \"tag_control_limit_active\": true,\r\n      \"tag_calc\": \"useless_field\",\r\n      \"tag_level\": 0,\r\n      \"tag_origine_dati\": null\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"IdOwner\": \"test\",\r\n      \"tag_id\": 6,\r\n      \"tag_type\": null,\r\n      \"tag_group\": null,\r\n      \"tag_name\": \"REW_SAX_BOWED_ActualVelocity\",\r\n      \"tag_sequence\": 0,\r\n      \"tag_description\": \"1\",\r\n      \"tag_short_descritpion\": \"1\",\r\n      \"tag_um\": null,\r\n      \"tag_active\": true,\r\n      \"tag_collecting\": true,\r\n      \"tag_data_edit\": false,\r\n      \"tag_source_name\": \"REW_SAX_BOWED.ACTUALVELOCITY\",\r\n      \"tag_source_index\": \"0\",\r\n      \"tag_source_tagtype\": \"Float\",\r\n      \"tag_source_lenght\": 0,\r\n      \"tag_collect_frequency\": 100,\r\n      \"tag_collect_unit\": \"1\",\r\n      \"tag_low_limit\": 1.0,\r\n      \"tag_high_limit\": 1.0,\r\n      \"tag_control_limit_active\": false,\r\n      \"tag_calc\": null,\r\n      \"tag_level\": 0,\r\n      \"tag_origine_dati\": null\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"IdOwner\": \"test\",\r\n      \"tag_id\": 7,\r\n      \"tag_type\": null,\r\n      \"tag_group\": null,\r\n      \"tag_name\": \"REW_SAX_BOWED_ActualVelocity\",\r\n      \"tag_sequence\": 0,\r\n      \"tag_description\": \"1\",\r\n      \"tag_short_descritpion\": \"1\",\r\n      \"tag_um\": null,\r\n      \"tag_active\": true,\r\n      \"tag_collecting\": true,\r\n      \"tag_data_edit\": false,\r\n      \"tag_source_name\": \"REW_SAX_BOWED.ACTUALVELOCITY\",\r\n      \"tag_source_index\": \"0\",\r\n      \"tag_source_tagtype\": \"Float\",\r\n      \"tag_source_lenght\": 0,\r\n      \"tag_collect_frequency\": 100,\r\n      \"tag_collect_unit\": \"1\",\r\n      \"tag_low_limit\": 1.0,\r\n      \"tag_high_limit\": 1.0,\r\n      \"tag_control_limit_active\": false,\r\n      \"tag_calc\": null,\r\n      \"tag_level\": 0,\r\n      \"tag_origine_dati\": \"Tag Name=REW_SAX_BOWED_ActualVelocity,Address=REW_SAX_BOWED.ACTUALVELOCITY,Data Type=Float,Respect Data Type=0,Client Access=RO,Scan Rate=100,Scaling=,Raw Low=,Raw High=,Scaled Low=,Scaled High=,Scaled Data Type=,Clamp Low=,Clamp High=,Eng Units=,Description=,Negate Value=,\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"IdOwner\": \"test\",\r\n      \"tag_id\": 8,\r\n      \"tag_type\": null,\r\n      \"tag_group\": null,\r\n      \"tag_name\": \"REW_SAX_BOWED_ActualVelocity\",\r\n      \"tag_sequence\": 0,\r\n      \"tag_description\": \"1\",\r\n      \"tag_short_descritpion\": \"1\",\r\n      \"tag_um\": null,\r\n      \"tag_active\": true,\r\n      \"tag_collecting\": true,\r\n      \"tag_data_edit\": false,\r\n      \"tag_source_name\": \"REW_SAX_BOWED.ACTUALVELOCITY\",\r\n      \"tag_source_index\": \"0\",\r\n      \"tag_source_tagtype\": \"Float\",\r\n      \"tag_source_lenght\": 0,\r\n      \"tag_collect_frequency\": 100,\r\n      \"tag_collect_unit\": \"1\",\r\n      \"tag_low_limit\": 1.0,\r\n      \"tag_high_limit\": 1.0,\r\n      \"tag_control_limit_active\": false,\r\n      \"tag_calc\": null,\r\n      \"tag_level\": 0,\r\n      \"tag_origine_dati\": \"Tag Name=REW_SAX_BOWED_ActualVelocity,Address=REW_SAX_BOWED.ACTUALVELOCITY,Data Type=Float,Respect Data Type=0,Client Access=RO,Scan Rate=100,Scaling=,Raw Low=,Raw High=,Scaled Low=,Scaled High=,Scaled Data Type=,Clamp Low=,Clamp High=,Eng Units=,Description=,Negate Value=,\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"IdOwner\": \"test\",\r\n      \"tag_id\": 9,\r\n      \"tag_type\": null,\r\n      \"tag_group\": null,\r\n      \"tag_name\": \"REW_SAX_BOWED_ActualVelocity\",\r\n      \"tag_sequence\": 0,\r\n      \"tag_description\": \"1\",\r\n      \"tag_short_descritpion\": \"1\",\r\n      \"tag_um\": null,\r\n      \"tag_active\": true,\r\n      \"tag_collecting\": true,\r\n      \"tag_data_edit\": false,\r\n      \"tag_source_name\": \"REW_SAX_BOWED.ACTUALVELOCITY\",\r\n      \"tag_source_index\": \"0\",\r\n      \"tag_source_tagtype\": \"Float\",\r\n      \"tag_source_lenght\": 0,\r\n      \"tag_collect_frequency\": 100,\r\n      \"tag_collect_unit\": \"1\",\r\n      \"tag_low_limit\": 1.0,\r\n      \"tag_high_limit\": 1.0,\r\n      \"tag_control_limit_active\": false,\r\n      \"tag_calc\": null,\r\n      \"tag_level\": 0,\r\n      \"tag_origine_dati\": \"Tag Name=REW_SAX_BOWED_ActualVelocity,Address=REW_SAX_BOWED.ACTUALVELOCITY,Data Type=Float,Respect Data Type=0,Client Access=RO,Scan Rate=100,Scaling=,Raw Low=,Raw High=,Scaled Low=,Scaled High=,Scaled Data Type=,Clamp Low=,Clamp High=,Eng Units=,Description=,Negate Value=,\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"IdOwner\": \"test\",\r\n      \"tag_id\": 10,\r\n      \"tag_type\": null,\r\n      \"tag_group\": null,\r\n      \"tag_name\": \"REW_SAX_BOWED_ActualVelocity\",\r\n      \"tag_sequence\": 0,\r\n      \"tag_description\": \"1\",\r\n      \"tag_short_descritpion\": \"1\",\r\n      \"tag_um\": null,\r\n      \"tag_active\": true,\r\n      \"tag_collecting\": true,\r\n      \"tag_data_edit\": false,\r\n      \"tag_source_name\": \"REW_SAX_BOWED.ACTUALVELOCITY\",\r\n      \"tag_source_index\": \"0\",\r\n      \"tag_source_tagtype\": \"Float\",\r\n      \"tag_source_lenght\": 0,\r\n      \"tag_collect_frequency\": 100,\r\n      \"tag_collect_unit\": \"1\",\r\n      \"tag_low_limit\": 1.0,\r\n      \"tag_high_limit\": 1.0,\r\n      \"tag_control_limit_active\": false,\r\n      \"tag_calc\": null,\r\n      \"tag_level\": 0,\r\n      \"tag_origine_dati\": \"Tag Name=REW_SAX_BOWED_ActualVelocity,Address=REW_SAX_BOWED.ACTUALVELOCITY,Data Type=Float,Respect Data Type=0,Client Access=RO,Scan Rate=100,Scaling=,Raw Low=,Raw High=,Scaled Low=,Scaled High=,Scaled Data Type=,Clamp Low=,Clamp High=,Eng Units=,Description=,Negate Value=,\"\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}"An exception occured: Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got String. Path '', line 1, position 9919.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your answer, it's been really useful.
I was wondering if making a sort of "substring" deleting the "{ Table:" part and the last } could work? 
Thank you anyway.

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After almost a year of practice with json i decided to answer my question. If you're actually trying to deserialize a json into a datatable we can assume you're using **vb.net** or **c#** (in other words visual studio).

To achive this task follow my list:

**0)** Download and install Newtonsoft.json from Nuget 
**1)** Copy your raw json
**2)** create a new class in your solution and name it as you want. (example: **MyDatatable.vb**)
**3)** In the Mydatatable.vb page : **Modify -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as clas**s (this is the key)

At this point visual studio will start creating a bunch of classes that will help newtonsoft to deserialize your json into the main object. In my case the main object was a class named **Table**  like you can see below :

> "{\r\n \"**Table**\": [\r\n {\r\n \"IdOwner\": \"Davide\",\r\n \"tag_id\":
>   1,\r\n \"tag_type\": \"3\",\r\n \"tag_group\": \"Group_2\",\r\n
>   \"tag_name\": \"Alfa\",\r\n \"tag_sequence\": 123458,\r\n
>   \"tag_description\": \"Description_2\",\r\n \"tag_short_descritpion\":
>   \"Desc_2\",\r\n \"tag_um\": \"kg\",\r\n \"tag_active\": true,\r\n
>   \"tag_colle

**4)** At this point you will have

- A class file named MyDatatable.vb containing many other classes like (***Table**)
- Newtonsoft reference installed on your project

this will allow you to deserialize your json with 2 instructions which are:

```
Dim strMyJson as string = [your raw json here]
Dim tbFinalObject as Table = Newtonsoft.json.jsonconver.deserializeObject(of Table)(strMyJson)
```

So in your tbFinalObject Object you'll have your json deserialized. 
Note: if the second instruction gives you an error like 'expected some char at line x' this may be because your json needs to be deserialized into a string before to be deserialized into another object so you should have a set of instructions like below:

```
 Dim strMyJson as string = [your raw json here]
 Dim strMyJson as string = Newtonsoft.json.jsonconvert.deserializeObject(of string)([your raw json here])
 Dim tbFinalObject as Table = Newtonsoft.json.jsonconvert.deserializeObject(of Table)(strMyJson)
```

That's how i solve most of my issues with json and vb.net deserializations.

*Further Notes: When you paste a json as class visual studio will automatically create object and create some property as arrays. I use to replace arrays with lists because i found that some old versions of newtonsoft have some problems deserializing json into arrays.*

Answer (score 6):

First you need to remove this line:

```
Dim json_jsonstring = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json_result)
```

The downloaded string is *already* JSON, if you serialize it *again* you will turn it into an escaped JSON string literal, whereupon deserializing it returns the string - and not a `DataTable` as you want.  This explains the error `Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got String. Path '', line 1, position 9919`: Json.NET parsed the entire `json_jsonstring` string as a single, escaped string literal.

Second, your JSON contains an outer root object like so:

```
{
  "Table": [
    {
      "IdOwner": "Davide", 
      // Additional properties
    },
    // Additional rows.
  ]
}
```

Thus you need to introduce a root object with the necessary `Table` property to deserialize the `DataTable` into.  You can do it with the following generic root:

```
Class RootObject(Of T)
    Public Property Table As T
End Class
```

And then deserialize as follows:

```
Dim table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject(Of DataTable))(json_result).Table
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EG8Yyk).

Or, if you don't care to create a root type, [deserialize to a temporary `Dictionary(Of string, DataTable)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#Dictionarys):

```
Dim table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of string, DataTable))(json_result).Values.SingleOrDefault()
```

Sample [fiddle #2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/90p9Ve):

You asked, *I was wondering if making a sort of "substring" deleting the "{ Table:" part and the last } could work?*  Certainly it's possible but I would not recommend this.  You would be manually duplicating some of the logic of a JSON parser.  Let Json.NET do the work for you, it will handle whitespace and newlines correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Download Newtonsoft Dll file https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

```
Imports Newtonsoft

Dim json As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Data.json"))
Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable

dt = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(json)
```