# Issue with Converting JSON to VB.NET datatable

Tags: json, vb.net

following is me JSON response text. I validated response and there is no error.
I am trying to convert it to data table but it gives me null or error.

**JSON Response:**

```
    {
  "data": {
    "b2b": [
      {
        "inv": [
          {
            "itms": [
              {
                "num": 1,
                "itc": {
                  "tx_cs": 0,
                  "elg": "ip",
                  "tx_i": 180
                },
                "itm_det": {
                  "csamt": 0,
                  "rt": 18,
                  "txval": 1000,
                  "iamt": 180
                }
              }
            ],
            "val": 1000,
            "inv_typ": "R",
            "flag": "N",
            "updby": "S",
            "pos": "27",
            "idt": "24-07-2017",
            "rchrg": "N",
            "cflag": "U",
            "inum": "191001",
            "chksum": "52d0e920428464d85721bfcd7f3bfb4f16fd00d93a9df7d6a6f0814bed716c28"
          },
          {
            "itms": [
              {
                "num": 1,
                "itc": {
                  "tx_cs": 0,
                  "elg": "ip",
                  "tx_i": 18
                },
                "itm_det": {
                  "csamt": 0,
                  "rt": 18,
                  "txval": 100,
                  "iamt": 18
                }
              }
            ],
            "val": 100,
            "inv_typ": "R",
            "flag": "N",
            "updby": "S",
            "pos": "27",
            "idt": "24-07-2017",
            "rchrg": "N",
            "cflag": "U",
            "inum": "191002",
            "chksum": "aaa1efcf335549b58059c9f3d03807d7c41b007022216f8a90db12c60cd2b9ef"
          }
        ],
        "cfs": "N",
        "ctin": "1225586"
      }
    ]
  },
  "header": {
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "gstin": "65656451",
    "retperiod": "072017",
    "gst_username": "sampleaccount",
    "state_cd": "27",
    "ip_address": "192.168.2.200",
    "txn": "s4f5sdf54sdf5s4df5",
    "client_id": "removedfortest",
    "client_secret": "removedfortest",
    "authorization": "Basic a4s5df45asdf54as5d4f",
    "ret_period": "072017"
  },
  "status_cd": "1",
  "status_desc": "request succeeds"
}
```

---

**Following are the classes i defined**

```
Public Class Itc
        Public Property tx_cs As Integer
        Public Property elg As String
        Public Property tx_i As Integer
    End Class

    Public Class ItmDet
        Public Property csamt As Integer
        Public Property rt As Integer
        Public Property txval As Integer
        Public Property iamt As Integer
    End Class

    Public Class Itm
        Public Property num As Integer
        Public Property itc As Itc
        Public Property itm_det As ItmDet
    End Class

    Public Class Inv
        Public Property itms As Itm()
        Public Property val As Integer
        Public Property inv_typ As String
        Public Property flag As String
        Public Property updby As String
        Public Property pos As String
        Public Property idt As String
        Public Property rchrg As String
        Public Property cflag As String
        Public Property inum As String
        Public Property chksum As String
    End Class

    Public Class B2b
        Public Property inv As Inv()
        Public Property cfs As String
        Public Property ctin As String
    End Class

    Public Class Data
        Public Property b2b As B2b()
    End Class

    Public Class Header
        Public Property email As String
        Public Property gstin As String
        Public Property retperiod As String
        Public Property gst_username As String
        Public Property state_cd As String
        Public Property ip_address As String
        Public Property txn As String
        Public Property client_id As String
        Public Property client_secret As String
        Public Property authorization As String
        Public Property ret_period As String
    End Class

    Public Class Example
        Public Property data As Data
        Public Property status_cd As String
        Public Property status_desc As String
        Public Property header As Header
    End Class
```

---

**and then i am trying to do following:**

Following return me Null in datatable

```
Dim table as datatable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject(Of DataTable))(responsetext).Table
```

also tried:
following does not allow me to type in rootofTable.data

```
    Dim rootOfList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject(Of List(Of data)))(responsetext)
Dim table As DataTable = rootOfTable.data
```

None of these are returning me values to datatable.
Dataset stay null.

**This is what i want**
[image]

Please help to resolve.

Thanks

Comment: a datatable is essentially a flat, 2-dimensional structure. Your JSON data has multiple layers. It's unclear even what actual result you would expect to see in the DataTable, let alone how you imagine .NET is going to guess how it should interpret your data into a set of flat rows and columns. What result do you want, exactly? Please show an example.

Comment: P.S. if your code throws an error, you should always tell people what that error is. We can't guess, and it won't always be obvious just from reading the code. And clearly it's very hard to suggest a fix for an unknown error. Don't make it hard for people to help you, instead, tell them exactly what you are trying to achieve, and exactly what is going wrong when you try. Those two pieces of information are both missing from your question. Thanks.

Comment: As ADyson said, inv has many itms you have to treat it like an array like itms.num.ItmDet.csamt(index) let's say 0 to get the first csamt occurrence, 1 for second and so on..

Comment: did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41892086/convert-json-to-datatable-vb

Comment: yes, i did check that question, was working to resolve this since 2 days. That question has two answers and tried both way. I understand that repose is "Multi-Dimensional Arrays" and hence it is getting hard for me to resolve it. @ADyson, i would surely mention error but it does not throw me error, just datatable stays with null value.

Comment: you said " it gives me null or error"...so I assumed that there was an error at least sometimes. If there isn't, then please remove that wording from your question, because it's not helpful. Please try and make your question clear, specific and not including irrelevant, redundant or inaccurate information. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. you still need to explain what result you are actually expecting to see in your datatable, and give an example of it (based on your sample JSON), otherwise we can't really advise you what alternative approach to take. As I said, there's no obvious direct translation from one data structure to the other, so you're going to have to tell us exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Based on your screenshot, you are going to need some custom code to flatten your structure. Deserialise the JSON to the class structure you've got, with RootObject at the top, and then you'll need to traverse that structure with some extra code and add the right items to the DataTable. You might be able to employ a tool such as AutoMapper to help with it, maybe. But I don't think you can do it purely using Newtonsoft.JSON (unless someone else can suggest a way).

Comment: You can't just say datatable=JSON, you have to set where each part of json has to go.

Comment: @ADyson, can you or someone please help with desired output. Because i tried lot and not able to do further. The classes i mentioned above are auto created by http://json2csharp.com/, but then i am stuck what to do next.

Comment: I've just told you what to do next. Read my last comment again, and CruleD's as well. You need to loop through the deserialised objects and place each field in the correct part of the DataTable, by hand (or by configuring a mapping tool). There's no direct mapping between them. Is there a particular part of that process you don't understand? I assume you know how to make a loop? And you can easily find out how to add rows and fields to a datatable by consulting the documentation and examples. I think you've got enough information to try and attempt this, but please ask if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 4 different ways it could be done (that I can think of) here is one example, I think it should be enough for you.

You basically just set which part of json goes into what column.

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim JsonP As JObject = JObject.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim SetPointer As JToken = JsonP("data")("b2b")(0)("inv")

    For Each item In SetPointer
        Dim NewDR As DataRow = TempDT.NewRow
        NewDR("val") = item("val")
        NewDR("inv_typ") = item("val")
        NewDR("flag") = item("flag")
        NewDR("updby") = item("updby")
        NewDR("pos") = item("pos")
        NewDR("idt") = item("idt")
        NewDR("rchrg") = item("rchrg")
        NewDR("cflag") = item("cflag")
        NewDR("inum") = item("inum")
        NewDR("chksum") = item("chksum")
        NewDR("itms_num") = item("itms")(0)("num")
        NewDR("itms_itc_cs") = item("itms")(0)("itc")("tx_cs")
        TempDT.Rows.Add(NewDR)
    Next
    DataGridView1.DataSource = TempDT
End Sub

Dim TempDT As New DataTable
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TempDT.Columns.Add("val")
    TempDT.Columns.Add("inv_typ")
    TempDT.Columns.Add("flag")
    TempDT.Columns.Add("updby")
    TempDT.Columns.Add("pos")
    TempDT.Columns.Add("idt")
    TempDT.Columns.Add("rchrg")
    TempDT.Columns.Add("cflag")
    TempDT.Columns.Add("inum")
    TempDT.Columns.Add("chksum")
    TempDT.Columns.Add("itms_num")
    TempDT.Columns.Add("itms_itc_cs")
End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

I didn't do everything, it's simply a demonstration of concept.

---

Use json visualizer. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ then as you navigate trough it you write out the name if it's {}, number if it's an array [] .

Like you can totally write out ("data")("b2b")(0)("inv")(0)("itms")(0)("itc")("tx_cs") to get value from it. But it would be easier to navigate to somewhere closer and then just write a part of it like ("itms").

And you can't write a fixed path for arrays most of the time as they have dynamic amount of members most of the time, so instead of (0) you will have to do (x) and loop over items.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CruleD , your detailed code perfectly helped me to understand and resolved my issue.