# vb.net convert string into map

Tags: mysql, arrays, string, vb.net

In my VB.Net project I am getting data from MySQL database in the following format:

```
[{"v":2.283175588,"p":"PASS"},{"v":2.373615284,"p":"PASS"},{"v":2.345711042,"p":"PASS"},{"v":2.365022001,"p":"PASS"}]'
```

I need to extract min and max value of `v`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse json and read in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943260/how-to-parse-json-and-read-in-vb-net)

Comment: you could do it in ,ysql or transfer json to a dataset https://stackoverflow.com/a/41894989/5193536

Comment: This is JSON data. You can write code using string manipulation to find "v", but utlimately you'll be **FAR** better served getting a JSON parser from Nuget into this project.